# How to restrict a div's size in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm making a custom dropdown component for my website, and so far I'm pretty happy, except for a couple things. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

This animation is done by changing the maxHeight attribute with state. However, the text itself doesn't get hidden as this transition happens:

[image]

Also, the div's area isn't shortened when it is close. You can click on the 'ghost' area to trigger the div:

[image]

How do I actually modify the height of the div and truncate everything that falls outside of it?
I'm sure the solution is some simple CSS trick I'm not aware of.

Relevant code:

```
const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = React.useState(defaultValue);
const [hoverState, setHoverState] = React.useState(primaryColor)


// Styles
const buttonstyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: '20px'
};


const menustyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    backgroundColor: hoverState, //primaryColor
    color: textColor,
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: '20px',
    padding: '5px 15px',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    transition: 'background-color 0.2s ease, max-height 0.5s ease',
    maxHeight: dropDownOpen ? '600px' : '23px',
    cursor: 'pointer'
};


function toggleDropDown(): void {
    setDropDownOpen(prev => !prev)
}


return (
    <div style={menustyle}
        onMouseEnter={onHover}
        onMouseLeave={onHoverExit}
        onClick={toggleDropDown}

    >
        <div
            style={buttonstyle}
        >
            {options[options.findIndex(item => item.value === currentOption)].label}
            <div style={{ // Maybe make it a hollow triangle with rounded edges?
                height: '15px',
                display: 'flex',
                transform: dropDownOpen ? '' : 'rotate(-180deg)',
                transition: 'transform 250ms ease',
            }}>
                <DropDownArrow fill="currentColor" />
            </div>
        </div>
        {/* Should add a divider here */}
        <div>
            <div>Ab</div>
            <div>A</div>
            <div>Bb</div>
            <div>B</div>
            <div>C</div>
            <div>Db</div>
            <div>D</div>
            <div>Eb</div>
            <div>E</div>
            <div>F</div>
            <div>Fb</div>
            <div>G</div>
        </div>

    </div>
);
```

Comment: overflow:hidden; would hide whats outside. It is missing in your styles

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Perfect! Easy CSS hack, as I expected. I really should go back and re-learn that stuff